# NameError: name 'stats' is not defined

Tags: python

i am messing about on python trying out classes but i am getting a name error which i dont know how to fix. it works fine when not in a class but now it is it doesnt work i presume this is a obvious problem , or just the whole thing is wrong, and i now look stupid lol, the other variables are things i havent got round to doing yet so ignore them. (yes the stats are ripped straight from fallout")

```
import time, random
class User():
        def players():
            players = 0
        def stats(self):
            perks = 20
            print ("you have 20 perk points to spend")
            print(""" you have several choices of what to spend
                        them in:
                        STRENGTH - what it says on the tin
                        PERCEPTION - awareness
                        ENDURANCE - how long you can endure something
                        CHARISMA - yet again what it says on the tin
                        INTELLIGENCE - how smart you are
                        AGILITY - how much of a slippery bugger you are
                        LUCK - how lucky you are""")
            strength = int(input("What level is your strength?"))
            perks = perks - strength
            perception = int(input("What level is your perception?"))
            perks = perks - perception
            endurance = int(input("What level is your endurance?"))
            perks = perks - endurance
            charisma = int(input("What level is your charisma?"))
            perks = perks - charisma
            intelligence = int(input("What level is your intelligence?"))
            perks = perks - intelligence
            agility = int(input("What level is your agility?"))
            perks = perks - agility
            luck = int(input("What level is your luck?"))
            perks = perks - luck

            if perks >= 0:
                print ("this works")
            elif perks <=-1:
                print("this also works")
        def __init__(self,username,stats):
            self.username = username
            self.stats = stats

            players +=1
story = "on"
while story ==  "on":
    print ("Start of story")    
    stats()


 Welcome to my story
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/----/----/python/----.py", line 45, in <module>
        stats()
    NameError: name 'stats' is not defined
    >>>
```

Comment: Please review your indentation. Also you're shadowing the method by assigning an attribute of the same name in `__init__`.

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is because the `stats` method/attribute (as jonrsharpe pointed out, you've used the name stats for both a method and an attribute) is defined only on the User class, and thus means nothing outside the context of a User instance. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) is the doc page on classes that you should take a look at.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that you have the `attribute` `stats` and the method `stats` you can rename your `stats` attribute to `_stats`, and also you need to make an object from `User` class for example

```
class User():

    def __init__(self,username,stats):
        self.username = username
        self._stats = stats
        ...

    def stats(self):
        ...


user = User('test', 1)
story = "on"
while story ==  "on":
    print ("Start of story")    
    user.stats() # method
    user._stats # attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

`stats()` is a method of your class `User`. That means `stats()` exists within the [scope](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example) of `User`, but out of the scope it is not defined.

Then there's another problem: Your `__init__` takes an argument with the same name (`stats`), and then you set `stats` as an attribute of `self`. That means you override your method `stats()` with whatever you pass to the `__init__` call (when you set `self.stats = stats`). You should rename this attribute, maybe to `self._stats = stats`.

And in your global scope, you have never [instantiated](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) your class `User`. So you could do something like this:

```
user = User("Jeremy", "whatever your stats are")
story = "on"
while story ==  "on":
    print ("Start of story")    
    user.stats()
```

This will resolve the error. However I'm not sure if the code will do what you expect it to do. You define a lot of variables within `stats()`, like `strength` etc. Maybe you'd want to define them as attributes to `self`, so `self.strength = ...`.

You can then access them in the global scope via `user.strength` etc.